# Drupal 7, implement jQuery UI Combobox widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, combobox

My name is Stefano.
I'd like to implement the [jQuery UI Combobox widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) in a Drupal 7 site.
I have jQuery Update module installed and enabled, configured with jQuery1.8 version and Google as jQuery and jQuery UI CDN.

In a random page filtered with php i put, at the top of the page, this php code:

```
<?php
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.core');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.widget');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.mouse');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.button');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.position');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.autocomplete');
    drupal_add_js('themes/bartik/autocomp.js', 'file');
?>
```

and then, right next the php, i put the select required with relative items:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label>Your preferred programming language: </label>
<select id="combobox">
<option value="">Select one...</option>
<option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
<option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
<option value="Asp">Asp</option>
<option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="C++">C++</option>
<option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
<option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
<option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
<option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
<option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
<option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
<option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
<option value="Java">Java</option>
<option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
<option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
<option value="Perl">Perl</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="Python">Python</option>
<option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
<option value="Scala">Scala</option>
<option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
</select>
</div>
```

the script included at the top in php, contained in autocomp.js, copied and pasted from jQuery UI widget page, is this:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
  _create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
      .insertAfter( this.element );

    this.element.hide();
    this._createAutocomplete();
    this._createShowAllButton();
  },

  _createAutocomplete: function() {
    var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

    this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
      })
      .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
      });

    this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
      },

      autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    });
  },

  _createShowAllButton: function() {
    var input = this.input,
      wasOpen = false;

    $( "<a>" )
      .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
      .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
      .tooltip()
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
      })
      .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
      .mousedown(function() {
        wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
      })
      .click(function() {
        input.focus();

        // Close if already visible
        if ( wasOpen ) {
          return;
        }

        // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
      });
  },

  _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
        return {
          label: text,
          value: text,
          option: this
        };
    }) );
  },

  _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

    // Selected an item, nothing to do
    if ( ui.item ) {
      return;
    }

    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
    var value = this.input.val(),
      valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
      valid = false;
    this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
      if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
        this.selected = valid = true;
        return false;
      }
    });

    // Found a match, nothing to do
    if ( valid ) {
      return;
    }

    // Remove invalid value
    this.input
      .val( "" )
      .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
      .tooltip( "open" );
    this.element.val( "" );
    this._delay(function() {
      this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
    }, 2500 );
    this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
  },

  _destroy: function() {
    this.wrapper.remove();
    this.element.show();
  }
});
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

The result is this one:

[Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZflSoKYtA5a2ZfZ3JDNVlDZ1k/edit?usp=sharing)

A normal, ugly select.

Where am I wrong?
Thanks evrybody for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you targeting

```
$.widget('select#combobox')
```

on your line 2 of autocomp, instead of custom.combobox ?

Comment: I have just tried... It doesn't seems to work. On jQuery official page  the code is the same as mine

Comment: Did you make sure that all necessary js files were loaded? especially autocomp.js